# Postman export JSON Object from Console

Tags: json, xml, postman

I parsed a XML response from Postman to an JSON Object using

```
var jsonObject = xml2Json(responseBody);
console.log(jsonObject);
```

I now get the correct JSON Object printed into the console but I cant figure out how to export it as a JSON Object. There is just the option of copying the log which wont export the JSON correctly.

[Screenshot of console log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3zqGg.png)

How can I export the generated JSON Object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to update your console.log like:

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(jsonObject));
```

And then copy/export your JsonObject from the console.